# Simplify VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, optimization

I have a macro which reads and writes data from two sheets in the same workbook.

**Is it possible to clean up and simplify the code/statements to improve readability and aid in debugging efforts?**

The statements have become so long they are confusing to read even when using the `space-underscore` method to use more than a single line.

Example of a statement which has become unwieldy:

```
Range("mx_plan").Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(sortedAircraft.Item(i).tailNumber, Range("aircraft")), WorksheetFunction.Match(currentWeekId, Range("week_id")) + weekly_hours_col_offset) = (acft_hoursDNE / acft_weeksRemaining)
```

I've intentionally tried to avoid making explicit references to individual cells or ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is 225 characters!

Debugging it will be impossible, because *it's one instruction doing way too many things*, and you can only place a breakpoint on a line of code... so you can't break and inspect any of the intermediary values you're using.

Break it down:

```
tailNumber = sortedAircraft.Item(i).tailNumber
aircraft = someSheet.Range("aircraft").Value
planRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(tailNumber, aircraft)

weekId = someSheet.Range("week_id").Value
planColumn = WorksheetFunction.Match(currentWeekId, weekId)

Set target = someSheet.Range("mx_plan").Cells(planRow, planColumn + weekly_hours_col_offset)
target.Value = acft_hoursDNE / acft_weeksRemaining
```

Remember to *declare* (`Dim`) all variables you're using (use `Option Explicit` to make sure the code won't compile if you make a typo with a variable name), use *meaningful names* for all identifiers (names that tell the reader *what* they're for - use comments when the *why* isn't obvious from the code alone).

By breaking it down into multiple smaller steps, you're not only making it easier to read/maintain, you're also making it easier to debug, because a runtime error will be raised in a specific instruction on a specific line, and you'll be able to more easily pinpoint the faulty inputs.

Comment: re: 225 characters - Right?!?  Exactly my issue. Thanks for the advice on breaking it down.  I've tried to the max possible to use meaningful names, and the like. I'll get to work implementing that before this project gets out of hand.

Comment: @ZephyrMays feel free to post your working code (with as much context as possible) on [codereview.se] for help making it more readable, efficient, maintainable, etc.

Comment: Absolutely will do so.  I appreciate the time you and @Jeeped took to answer.  The act of breaking things down revealed an abundance of repetitive statements or partial statements which I've pulled out into separate variables as much as possible.  Anytime I see the same statement more than once, it's been easy to pull it out.  Nowthings are a ton more legible.

Comment: . @mats-mug - as suggested, I posted my project, after major clean up, over at [Code Review - here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/120772/98367).  Thanks again for the suggestions.  Getting back to basics with those statements has made all the difference in remembering what I was trying to do and why!

Answer (score 2):

Use [With ... End With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) statements to localize any [Range.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) property.

Declare and Set a variable to the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) that can be used as a replacement for the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx). This should make repeated calls to worksheet functions more readable.

Bring everything to the right of the equals sign down to the next line by supplying a `_` (e.g. chr(95)). This acts like a concatenation character and allows single code lines to be spread over two or more lines. I've also use it to line up the two [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) functions which return row and column to the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx).

```
Dim app As Application
Set app = Application

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("mx_plan")
    .Cells(app.Match(sortedAircraft.Item(i).tailNumber, Range("aircraft"), 0), _
           app.Match(currentWeekId, Range("week_id"), 0) + weekly_hours_col_offset) = _
      (acft_hoursDNE / acft_weeksRemaining)
End With

Set app = Nothing
```

That looks significantly more readable to my eye. Your use of named ranges may also be improved but it is hard to make suggestions without knowing the parent worksheets that each belongs to.

Note: I added a `, 0` to each of the MATCH functions to force an exact match on unsorted data. I do not know if this was your intention but without them the data in the **aircraft** and **week_id** named ranges must be sorted (see [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)).

Comment: Better indeed. Now, suppose `Range("aircraft")` contains a value that makes the entire statement blow up. Or that the `ActiveSheet` (which is implicitly referred to with the `Range` function used like this) isn't the expected one, and the named ranges can't be accessed. Fun? ;-)

Comment: Will try this out as well.